# Kotlin Realtime Firebase Post set autoincrement ID to database

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to save an Item to Firebase. When I save one Item, then my structure looks like i want to look, but I have problem with ID:

```
Trips
-My6qIbSx5dnSy2yScAr
  date: "Feb 20, 2022 12:00:00 AM"
  distance: "25"
  id: 0 <- here I want autoincrement ID
  name: "Test ONE"
-My6qUykRSjuxu_MnyO_
date: "Feb 20, 2022 12:00:00 AM"
  distance: "25"
  id: 0 <- here I want autoincrement ID
  name: "Test TWO"
```

I cannot put to field id my incremented id from above, which Firebase is adding, after putting Item to database.

I'm using api Firebase and my code looks like this :

```
Service:

 @POST("${FirebaseFactory.BASE_URL}/Trips.json")
suspend fun saveTrip(@Body trip : Item) {
}
```

And ViewModel:

```
val testPutTrips = client.saveTrip(Item("Test ONE", "25", "Feb 20, 2022 12:00:00 AM", here i'm nothing passsing, because my Model has autoincrement, but it doesnt work and always put me 0))
```

Model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "trip")
data class Item(
@ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "distance") val distance: String,
@ColumnInfo(name = "date") val date: Date,
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0)
```

Is it possible to put incremented ID to filed?

Comment: So what exactly would you like to achieve? You need to increment the `id` for each new document that you add?

Comment: I want to put to Value: id generated ID from Firebase. Is it possible?

Comment: F.ex. To Item : My6qIbSx5dnSy2yScAr i want to put it to value id. But I use andpoints and I don't have access to database.ref

Comment: So you need to have the value of `-My6qIbSx5dnSy2yScAr` added to the id property?

Comment: Exactly this is what I need

Comment: Show us the code that adds such an `-My6qIbSx5dnSy2yScAr` item in the database.

Answer (score 0):

From the Firebase documentation on [appending data to a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data):

> You can use the reference to the new data returned by the `push()` method to get the value of the child's auto-generated key or set data for the child. Calling `getKey()` on a `push()` reference returns the value of the auto-generated key.

In code it'd look something like:

```
val newRef = mDatabase.child("Trips").push();

yourObject.id = newRef.key;

newRef.setValue(yourObject);
```